# How to get VBScript and ASP Symbol Files

Tags: debugging, windbg, symbols

Many Windows system files are available from Microsoft through a download page or http path.  My WinDbg can't find the symbol files for VBScript.dll and ASP.dll and I can't seem to find them on the Internet.  The VBScript.dll on the server is 5.6.0.8835 and the ASP.dll is 6.0.3790.4195.  Both have younger file dates than their symbol files in the download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/symbolpkg.mspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to use the Microsoft symbol server at http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ ?

See [Debugging Tools and Symbols: Getting Started](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/debugstart.mspx) documentation page for information about how to use the symbol server in WinDbg.
The basic specification in WinDbg for the symbol path can include:

```
SRV*c:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Change c:\websymbols to the desired download store, or remove it for no local stored cache.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that.  Got that in my environment variables.